# Token undefined on first render in next-auth causes useSuspenseQuery to fetch with no bearer token set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query

I am using the new useSuspenseQuery from react-query and I noticed that the enabled property is not present on this hook. My useGetApiToken returns null on first render and because of this, the suspenseQuery fetches with null as value for the bearer token.

One way to solve this is to put the refetchInterval property very low (500ms - 1000ms), but this comes at the cost of constantly polling my api with requests.

Answer (score 1):

Going to answer this myself as this was an issue I was stuck with.

Basically you need to fetch your session on the server and pass that as value to your SessionProvider. That way your SessionProvider returns the token on first render instead of undefined/null.

I am using next auth v5 and there they created a new helper called function auth() which fetches the session on the server. See: https://authjs.dev/guides/upgrade-to-v5

In app/layout.tsx

```
export default async function RootLayout({ children }: { children: any }) {
  const session = await auth();
  return (
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.svg" />
      </head>
      <body className="overflow-x-clip h-auto">
        <Providers session={session}>
          {children}
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

In app/providers.tsx

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({})

export const Providers = ({
  children,
  session,
}:{
  children: any
  session: Session;
}) => (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          {children}
        </QueryClientProvider>
    </SessionProvider>
);
```

My useGetApiToken

```
'use client';

import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

export const useGetApiToken = () => {
  const { data: session } = useSession({ required: false });
  return session?.user?.accessToken;
};
```

Finally for the useSuspenseQuery

```
export const useFetch = (
  id: string,
  options?: UseSuspenseQueryOptions<Foo>
) => {
  const token = useGetApiToken();
  
  return useSuspenseQuery({
    queryFn: () => fetch(id, token),
    ...options,
    queryKey: ['fetch'],
  });
};
```